# Inequality for differences of ordered eigenvalues of nearby matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nuclear-norm

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive semidefinite finite dimensional matrices with unit trace such that $|A-B|_1\leq \varepsilon$ where one can choose any nonzero $\varepsilon$.

Let $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2 \geq ... \geq \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ in decreasing order and let $\mu_1\geq \mu_2 \geq ... \geq \mu_n$ be the eigenvalues of $B$. Is there a upper bound one can place on

$$|\lambda_i - \mu_i|$$

for all choices of $i$? I can show the bound $1/2$ for small enough $\varepsilon$ but it feels not tight.

Comment: Please state explicitly what you mean by $|\cdot|_1$. Based on the tags, it seems that this refers to the nuclear norm

Comment: Note also that the term "positive semidefinite" is used in some contexts to refer only to symmetric/Hermtian matrices, but sometimes the definition is used in a more general sense. Are the matrices $A$ and $B$ symmetric/Hermitian?

Comment: @BenGrossmann sorry about not making those points clear but your assumptions are correct. It was the nuclear norm and the matrices were Hermitian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric real matrices (or complex self-adjoint matrices). I assume that $|\cdot|_1$ denotes the nuclear norm.

Let $\rho_1 \geq \cdots \geq \rho_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $A-B$. [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory) tell us that for all $j = 1,\dots, n,$ we have
$$
\mu_j + \rho_n \leq \lambda_j \leq \mu_j + \rho_1 \implies\\
\rho_n \leq \lambda_j - \mu_j \leq \rho_1. 
$$
However, we have
$$
|A-B|_1 = |\rho_1| + \cdots + |\rho_n| \leq \epsilon,
$$
which implies that $|\rho_j| \leq \epsilon$ for all $j$, so that $\rho_n \geq - \epsilon$ and $\rho_1 \leq \epsilon$.

With that, we conclude that $|\lambda_j - \mu_j| \leq \epsilon$. This bound is tight, as can be seen by considering certain diagonal matrices $A$ and $B$.